# JavaFX - ComboBox.setEditable() Index out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, edit

I wish to have a combo box that when a specific item is selected the combo box becomes editable. Unfortunately my code for this keeps throwing an exception:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class Main extends Application
{      
  ComboBox<String> comboBox;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)
  {
    comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.getItems().add("Editable Item");
    comboBox.setOnAction(e -> comboBox.setEditable(true));

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().add(comboBox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 128, 128);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$178(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior$$Lambda$128/1234852073.onChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$183/1274446857.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1232367853.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Is it possible to make a combo box editable when a particular item is selected?

Comment: Post the stack trace. `getValue()` would throw an NPE before `setEditable` if `comboBox` was `null`, so it would be strange if `setEditable` was throwing the NPE

Comment: I have included the stack trace as requested and added a println to show the state of the variable before the if statement.

Comment: What's at line 59 of `Controller`?

Comment: @VinceEmigh comboBox.setEditable(true);

Comment: Have you ever used a debugger? If you're using Eclipse, create a breakpoint on the line with the print statement and the line your error occurs. When you run in debug mode, execution will pause when a breakpoint is reached. Open up the Variables view (Window > Show View > Other... > Variables) and check to see if checkBox is `null`. Like I said, if `comboBox.setEditable()` throws an NPE, `comboBox.getValue()` should have thrown the NPE before getting to `setEditable`. Check to see if it's actually null by stepping through this with a debugger

Comment: @VinceEmigh Unfortunately I can't get debug mode working, I keep getting an unrelated source not found error.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you isolate the problem, as well as let us execute that code (to reproduce the error) allowing us to debug

Comment: @Vince Emigh I've changed my code so that it is a MCVE

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? It seems there were a few bugs relating to this issue with previous releases, so it could be due to you using an outdated version of FX (that contains bugs). From what I'm finding online, you should call that method within a [runLater(Runnable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-). See if that fixes your issue, as the current stack trace you are showing us (since you've updated your post) does not involve code you have written.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Not too sure what I'd be doing with that runLater() method, I've gone an alternative route and decided to just make a popup appear when the editable item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your NPE is thrown by this line

```
if(item.equals(editableItem))
```

where `item` is null.
To keep such equations NPE safe you should rather do

```
if("editable".equals(item))
```

This would never thorw NPE even if `item` would be null.

Comment: It won't throw an NPE, but it'll still give him incorrect results. All this is doing is converting it into a logic problem. The `equals` for null check trick is neat, but is a horrible bandaid that doesn't fix the situation (in this case, at least). Not to mention, I'm kind of wondering what makes you think `item` is `null`, as there's nothing in his code that would suggest it (other than you assuming that's the problem, since you might feel `comboBox` isn't `null`)

Comment: @VinceEmigh because right before NPE console says so?

Comment: The console says line 59 of Controller.java. Do you know which line is 59? Because he didn't label the line numbers in his code, he's telling us which line is line 59, and I don't see anything in the stack trace suggesting it would be `item`. I wasn't trying to be rude, I'm just not understanding how you came to this conclusion. What am I not seeing that you are? One could only make an assumpsiom that `item` was `null`, seeing how there's no word about it in the stack trace.

Comment: the console says `Combo Box Item: null` - this is what u are not seeing,

Comment: @VinceEmigh i guess that is it. Forgot to mention u in previous comment

Comment: I don't see that in the console. I used "find" (cntrl+f) to search for it all occurances of `null` on this page, but couldn't find anything related to *Combo Box Item: null*. Did you actually run it and get that result? Because I didn't run it; there wasn't enough code at the time to properly run it. I'm attempting to reproduce the error (using the MCVE he posted), and I'm not getting an NPE as a result, or the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` he seems to be getting now. His new stacktrace does not mention an NPE

Comment: OP edited the stacktrace, it is not there anymore. Check the previous stacktrace

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks for responding. You're right about the NPE but I still get an IndexOutOfBounds exception when I try to execute the setEditable() method.

Comment: @VinceEmigh as u can see i was right. OP has another problem now

Comment: Yes, after reviewing the edits, I have realized that `item` was `null` due to what was printed. That was my mistake for not noticing the printed statements at the top of the console. But that doesn't change the fact that using the "equals null check" trick doesn't actually solve the problem, rather than make it a logical problem (shouldn't return false, although it does). I'm starting to believe the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception is caused by a bug from a previous release, as the research I have done on this lead me to articles about such a bug (involving `ComboBox`). That was my main point